# Использование COM объекта Excel.Application

Tags: 1с, com, excel

При выгрузке в Excel из 1С, посредством объекта "Excel.Application", выгружаются не все данные. Могут ли это быть проблемы самого COM-объекта? И какие типичные проблемы, самого COM-объекта, могут возникать при такой выгрузке?

Comment: Вряд ли. Проблемы, скорее всего, с 1С. Возможны проблемы из-за "неправильной" версии Excel (что опять же проблемы 1С)

Comment: Переписал код в 1с проблема не исчезла! Данные со стороны 1с передаются com объекту в полном объеме. Выгрузка, точнее конечный excel файл останавливается на той же строке, как и в предыдущем варианте 1с кода написанного другим программистом. Если вдруг у кого случались такие проблемы, сообщите как Вы с ними боролись!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel, как OLE сервер, меня ни разу не подводил(использую более 10 лет). Приведите примеры кода.

Кстати, есть хорошие примеры, правда для Fox'а - http://vfox.kristall.ru/excel.html

Comment: Перестал искать проблему! Решил переписать код в 1с. У меня также не было ранее проблем с com объектами Microsoft.